# Having problems booting xubuntu after installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, boot-failure, xubuntu

I'm newbie with ubuntu, I tried to install ubuntu, at the beginning xubuntu work for the first upgrade to xubuntu 12.04, but after the reboot, no winxp media center ether Xubuntu won't start and I have a screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> nothing else. I read a little about, maybe the sata enabled on the bios. What is the problem and can it be fixed or do I have to remove xubuntu.

**Partition** is :

- 100gb xubuntu
- 220gb winxp
- I have an external drive 1 tb

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

can you press ctrl+alt+f2  (after login) and write this . `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop cream` after `sudo cream /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`  and change all codes to it

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=enes
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
greeter-show-manual-login = true
```